# Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, reactjs

I am working through the Lynda tutorial for React.js Essential training and am running into a problem with chapter 13 - Loading JSON with webpack.

When I try and compile and start the server I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/titles.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at JsonParser.parse (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\JsonParser.js:15:21)
    at doBuild.err (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:367:32)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:264:12)
    at C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:370:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:211:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:218:10)
    at C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:229:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:16)
    at provider (C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:79:9)
    at C:\Users\pauln\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:528:3)
 @ ./src/lib.js 12:14-38
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:2000 ./src/index.js

ERROR in chunk main [entry]
bundle.js
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

My titles.json file looks like this:

```
{   
    "hello": "Bonjour",
    "goodbye": "Au Reviour"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Adding my webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

    module.exports = {
        entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/dist/assets",
            filename: "bundle.js",
            publicPath: "assets",
        },
        devServer: {
            inline: true,
            contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
            port: 2000
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                enforce: "pre",
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
                }

            },

            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "json-loader"       
            }

            ]
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2** Adding lib.js file and index.js file

lib.js

```
 import React from 'react'
    import text from './titles.json'

    export const hello = (
        <h1 id='title'
            className='header'
            style={{backgroundColor: 'purple', color: 'yellow'}}>
            {text.hello}
            </h1>
            )

    export const goodbye = (
        <h1 id='title'
            className='header'
            style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', color: 'purple'}}>
            {text.goodbye}
            </h1>
        )
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { hello, goodbye } from './lib'

render(
    <div>
       { hello }
        { goodbye }
    </div>,
     document.getElementById('react-container')
     )
```

Comment: What does your webpack config look like?

Comment: Updated with my webpack.config file.

Comment: can you show where you're trying to import this json file?

Comment: Yes. I do have the .babelrc file. That was one of the earlier videos.

Comment: inside your `lib.js` add `import Text from '!json!./titles';` notice extra `!json!` at the start

Comment: Tried that but did not work. Received an error that said I needed to add -loader which I did but still with same issue as before.

Comment: After doing that inside your `webpack.config.js` add loader like : `{ test: /\.json$/, loaders: ['json-loader'] }`

Comment: @Aaqib adding !json! worked for me. Would you mind elaborating why/how this solved the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: @penone I would appreciate it if you would take time to mark my answer as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 82):

I had the same issue but when I check the json-loader documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/) I found out that `json-loader` isn't necessary anymore in webpack version greater than or equal to 2.0.
So you could remove the `json-loader` from your webpack config file and everything should work assuming you import your json file appropriately `import text from './titles.json'`

Comment: The json-loader documentation url is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 3):

`json-loader` is **not require**d anymore:

> ⚠️ Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default. You might still want to use this if you use a custom file extension.

Docs: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#json-loader-is-not-required-anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by ensuring no spacing on key and value on the JSON text

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar caused by invalid data in JSON (using it as .jsonc and having a comment)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to modify your `package.json` file to add a `browser` section:

```
"browser": {
  "colors": false,
  "events": "eventemitter3",
  "checkForModuleDuplicates": false,
  "url": "./shims/url",      
  "tracer": false
}
```

Webpack will respect this section and ignore anything set to `: false` or otherwise load the corresponding module from the value of the key:value pair.